# complexity reduction (refacto)

Tags: java, complexity

I'm trying to reduce the complexity of this piece of code following a SonarQube error. I have several similar blocks, and even if I try to extract them into private methods, the Sonar error persists.

There is the code :

```
if (contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() != null && fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite() != null) {
        if (contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null && fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null) {
            if (!(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance().equals(contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance()))) {
                contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().setAutoriteDelivrance(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance());
            }
        } else if (fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null) {
            contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().setAutoriteDelivrance(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance());
        } else if (contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null) {
            pieceIdentite.setAutoriteDelivrance(contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance());
                       }

    } else if (contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() == null && fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite() != null) {
        if (fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null) {
            contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().setAutoriteDelivrance(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance());
        }
    } else if (contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() != null && fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite() == null) {
        if (contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null) {
            pieceIdentite.setAutoriteDelivrance(contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance());
        }
    }
```

If anyone has a lead I'm interested :)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: @TobySpeight Your comment and (presumably) close vote don't match up. Please [read our meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8750) to understand the difference between NDOC (was UWYA) and MRC (was LCC).

Comment: @Peilonrayz, Am I only allowed to comment on the close vote?  That comes with its own comment if others agree.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Peilonrayz - and I don't understand why you think that comments need to "agree" with close votes.  The question is off-topic because it's missing important definitions (e.g. `contratPPH`, `fichePersonne`); if that's fixed it still needs a decent explanation and title.

Comment: @TobySpeight Closing for one reason and commenting exclusively another is confusing. E.g. "You've said X is the problem but closed for Y, what is the problem with my question?" Following up with a comment which says Y is off-topic but X is 'needed?' is also confusing. If I were an OP I'd feel like you're flip-flopping and moving the goal posts. I don't understand why you want to avoid saying "both X and Y make the question off-topic". Additionally "Am I only allowed to comment on the close vote?" is a false dichotomy, ofc you can say "X and Y are off-topic".

Answer (score 1):

First lets simplify the names and function calls to make reading the boolean logic of the code easier.

```java
if (A != null && B != null) {
    if (A.fn() != null && B.fn() != null) {
        if (A.fn() != B.fn()) {
            #1
        }
    } else if (B.fn() != null) {
        #1
    } else if (A.fn() != null) {
        #2
    }

} else if (!(A != null) && B != null) {
    if (B.fn() != null) {
        #1
    }
} else if (A != null && !(B != null)) {
    if (A.fn() != null) {
        #2
    }
}
```

Lets express the logic as a truth table:

| A != null | A.fn() != null | B != null | B.fn() != null | Choice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True | True | #1 |
| True | False | True | True | #1 |
| True | True | True | False | #2 |
| False | False | True | True | #1 |
| True | True | False | False | #2 |

You can probably notice the only columns in the table which change the outcome are `A.fn() != null` and `B.fn() != null`.
As such we can just merge `A != null` and `A.fn() != null` together, likewise for `B`, and rewrite the table.

| A | B | Choice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | #1 |
| False | True | #1 |
| True | False | #2 |
| False | False | N/A |

**Note**: The table does hide the `if (A != B)` check in the code.

```java
boolean A = A != null && A.fn() != null;
boolean B = B != null && B.fn() != null;

if (A && B) {
    if (A.fn() != B.fn()) {
        #1
    }
} else if (B) {
    #1
} else if (A) {
    #2
}
```

The first `if` look a little suspect to me.
I'd expect `#1` and `#2` or an `else if` to add the `#2`.
However I don't speak French so you may be updating a value.
I just want to point out a possible mistake.

Next the quirk in the code makes DRYing the duplicate `#1`s a little more complex.
We can roll the first three `if`s into a turnery `A && B ? A != B : B`.
However then the `else if` won't know `!B`.
So we can go two routes:

Separate `if`s, or start with an `if (B)`.

```java
if (A && B ? A.fn() != B.fn() : B) {
    #1
}
if (A && !B) {
    #2
}
```

```java
if (B) {
    if (A ? A.fn() != B.fn() : true) { // or (!A || A.fn() != B.fn())
        #1
    }
} else if (A) {
    #2
}
```

Converting the latter back to Java we get:

```java
boolean A = contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() != null && contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null;
boolean B = fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite() != null && fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null;

if (B) {
    if (!A || !contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance().equals(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance())) {
        contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().setAutoriteDelivrance(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance());
    }
} else if (A) {
    pieceIdentite.setAutoriteDelivrance(contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance());
}
```

We can further simplify the code by using [the null conditional operator `?.`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4390141) and comparing to `null` later.

```java
A = contratPPH.getPieceIdentite()?.getAutoriteDelivrance();
B = fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite()?.getAutoriteDelivrance();

if (B != null) {
    if (A == null || !A.equals(B)) {
        contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().setAutoriteDelivrance(B);
    }
} else if (A != null) {
    pieceIdentite.setAutoriteDelivrance(A);
}
```

Comment: so `A = contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() != null`, `B = fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite() != null`, `A.fn() = contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null` and `B.fn() = fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null`. Then `A = A ? A : A.fn();` <=> `Boolean A = contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() != null ? contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() != null : contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance() != null`. Is that right ?

Comment: @goujon I made a mistake, I have updated my answer. `A != B` wasn't correct and I didn't allow the syntax to support the correct meaning. I have included the revised code at the bottom. Please note `A` probably should be named something else, but I don't know French.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the previous discussion with @Peilonrayz, I have a solution to propose. If I understood correctly we have 2 solutions :

```
A = A ? A : A.fn();
B = B ? B : B.fn();
if (A && B ? A != B : B) {
    #1
}
if (A && !B) {
    #2
}
```

or

```
A = A ? A : A.fn();
B = B ? B : B.fn();
if (B) {
   if (A ? A != B : true) { // or (!A || A != B)
      #1
   }
} else if (A) {
   #2
}
```

on choisissant la première solution, j'obtiens :

```
boolean A = contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() != null ? contratPPH.getPieceIdentite() != null : contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getType() != null;
boolean B = fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite() != null ? fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite() != null : fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getType() != null;

    if(A && B ? A != B : B) {
        contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().setType(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getType());
    }
    if(A && !B) {
        pieceIdentite.setType(contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().getType());
    }
```

@Peilonrayz could you confirm that I'm on the right way ?

Comment: The definition of `A` and `B` look correct. The replacement for `#1` and `#2` look really incorrect. I don't know how `contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().setAutoriteDelivrance(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getAutoriteDelivrance());` became `contratPPH.getPieceIdentite().setType(fichePersonne.getPieceIdentite().getType());` as the code never used `setType` and `getType`.

Comment: Really sorry, it's the same problem for another field

Comment: On a side note [answers must contain one Insightful Observation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please can you point to one issue with my code (a what) and show an improvement (a why) to bring your answer inline with site scope. If you don't please delete your answer (as you've got a response from me anyway). I also noticed `A ? A : A.fn()` could just be `A && A.fn()` (or better yet the [null conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4390141) `A?.fn()`) so the Insightful Observation should be easy to make.

Comment: in `if(A && B ? A != B : B)`, `A != B` is always false so as you said, I have to use `!A.equals(B)` but the reference is not known